# how to display error message in the top of post title if no category checked?

Tags: wordpress, post

I want to show error message if no category selected while adding a new post?

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it via jquery:

```
/* Checks if cat is selected when publish button is clicked */
jQuery( '#submitdiv' ).on( 'click', '#publish', function( e ) {
    var $checked = jQuery( '#category-all li input:checked' );

    //Checks if cat is selected
    if( $checked.length <= 0 ) {
        alert( "Please Select atleast one category" );
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
} );
```

and output error message as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the [admin_notices](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) hook. Just add the following code in your functions.php file:

```
function wp_823232_admin_notice__no_category_error()
{

    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e('Warning: No category is selected for this post!', 'sample-text-domain'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}


function wp_823232_check_category()
{

    global $pagenow;
    global $post;

    if ($pagenow == 'post-new.php' || $pagenow == 'post.php') {
        if (count(get_categories($post->ID)) == 1 && has_category("uncategorized", $post->ID)) {
            add_action('admin_notices', 'wp_823232_admin_notice__no_category_error');
        }

    }


}

add_action('in_admin_header', 'wp_823232_check_category');
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable ans. can you help how i can also make that post draft before calling wp_823232_admin_notice__no_category_error()

Comment: Posts are drafted automatically in WordPress or by saving them. wp_823232_admin_notice__no_category_error() will be called whenever a post is opened for editing, the editor is refreshed or a new post is being added.